# Open port 80 on Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm just starting out in Ubuntu/Linux, and have some trouble opening port 80 for incoming connections.

I ran the `sudo ufw allow 80/tcp` command, and when I run `sudo ufw status` the result looks like this:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

However, I still get this error when trying to connect to the port with cURL.

> Failed to connect to MY_IP_ADDRESS port 80: Connection refused

When I run this command `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` to see what ports are open, I get this result:

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Which doesn't look that promising..

How do I open port 80 for incoming connections?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no program listening on port 80 so it's closed and you can't connect to it.

You can use

```
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

For Python-3:

```
sudo python3 -m http.server 80
```

to start a simple web server listening on port 80, or install something like Apache (package `apache2`) if you want a full blown web server.

Comment: is it possible without `sudo` ?

Answer (score 17):

[**UFW**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) is the *Uncomplicated Firewall*. It manages what ports on your computer can be opened for listening by an application. `sudo ufw allow 80/tcp` means allow *TCP* connections to *port 80*.

However, there is nothing actually listening in behind the port. To `curl` the port, there should be an application that will send a reply. This is typically called a server. As @Florian points out, you can use *Python*'s `SimpleHTTPServer` to test it.

Comment: is this permanent?

Comment: @Idemax About `ufw`, I don't know. About `SimpleHTTPServer`, it lasts for as long as you run it.

Comment: Nope, not working ...

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Then to prevent it from losing the iptables configuration on restart, use:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

Comment: This would have been a great edit to [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/779745/283721) dated 4/2016

Answer (score 8):

well what worked for me was to use iptable

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: As a note this is not permanent. Will reset on reboot.

Comment: @OliverDixon, yes correct

Answer (score 5):

you can use `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` this accepts the port when it configures with the port to prevent from losing this terminal line of code you can use `sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent` 
The reason for sudo in the beggining of a command is to let it run as superuser the persistant uses it as a persistant connection to the port that is supplied. You can also use you can use Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` to test it! This was a great question! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me 
Just Allow the 80 from iptables

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```